# Traps sometime stop working in OMD2?

Tags: orcs-must-die-2

I'm playing the "Passages" map on endless with my warmage. I made a killbox, but sometimes there's, like, an electric storm that happens in the killbox and all my traps stop working for a little while. Is this normal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have the 'Are We There Yeti?' dlc?

If so, I believe what you are experiencing is the Goblin Sapper.

> The Goblin Sapper, introduced in the Are We There Yeti? DLC, is a
>   small fast-moving enemy that attempts to disable certain Traps by
>   sprinting to them and exploding. They behave similar to Kobold
>   Sappers, although they deal no damage to the player.

Notes

- Goblin Sappers are more damage-resistant than their Kobold counterparts, but they are vulnerable to lightning damage.
- A Lightning Ring is very effective at taking out groups of these enemies.
- When the Goblin Sapper explodes, **it disables any traps within 1-3 blocks of the explosion for 10 seconds**.
- **The afflicted traps will be surrounded by electric auras**.
- Some traps, such as Brimstone and Shock Zapper, will lose their stored charge, and will only recharge after the disable effect wears off.
- Using the Trap Reset Trinket will restore any disabled traps to full operational   status.

Source: http://orcsmustdie.wikia.com/wiki/Goblin_Sapper

Comment: That will be it. I haven't played those levels yet. And the specific map I had this on is as such that I can't see what's coming.